# Theta Series of D16+ lattice?

Tags: reference-request

What does the theta series of the even, unimodular, positive definite lattice D16+ look like? Also, is there a way to look this information up for any lattice?

Comment: What did you try? Do you have any ideas? Where and why did this question arise? It's hard to see how much you know about modular forms and theta series.

Comment: I know that the theta series is supposed to be a modular form of weight 8, and that modular forms of weight 8 are polynomials in the eisenstein series $E_8.$

Comment: The space of modular forms of weight 8 is 1-dimensional. Thus the theta series is a multiple of $E_8$.

Comment: I also know what the D16+ lattice looks like, i.e it consists of all vectors $(a_1,...,a_{16})$ such that either all the $a_i$ are integers or they are all integers plus 1/2, and their sum is even.

Comment: Alright, is there a way to find the multiplying factor?

Comment: start with http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/

Comment: Looking at the Fourier expansion is a possibility.

Comment: It's the square of the theta function for the $E_8$ lattice.

Comment: You can try the [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/Lattice/) site.

Comment: This does not need any sites or hard calculations. We know that the space of weight $8$ modular forms has dimension one. Moreover, we know a non-zero element: $E_8$ with constant fourier coefficient $a(0) = 1$. Now, it is obvious that the constant fourier coefficient of the theta series is equal to $1$. As a consequence, we obtain that they are equal. Analogously one sees the equality @LordSharktheUnknown mentions.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I have one last comment, this means that both the even unimodular lattices of dimension 16 have same theta series? Is that usually the case?

Comment: @anon The amount of even unimodular lattices of dimension $8n$ grows much faster then the dimension of the vector spaces of modular forms (for $n = 3$ we have $24$, for $n = 4$ there are more then a billion of them, while the corresponding dimensions are $1, 1, 2$). So in a sense, this should happen quite often.

Answer (score 0):

- $h(t) = e^{-\pi \|t\|^2}, t \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is its own Fourier transform. If $M \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ is an invertible matrix then the Fourier transform of $h(Mt) = e^{-\pi \|M t\|^2}$ is $\frac{1}{|\det M|} h(M^{-T} t)$.
- If $\Lambda = M \mathbb{Z}^k$ is a lattice then we define its theta series $$\Theta_\Lambda(x) = \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} e^{- \pi x \|\lambda\|^2} =\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^k} h(\sqrt{x} M n), \qquad \Re(x) > 0$$
  and with $H(n)=h((\sqrt{x}I) M n)$ the Poisson summation formula gives 
  $$\Theta_\Lambda(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^k} H(n)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^k} \widehat{H}(n)= \frac{x^{-k/2}}{|\det M|} \Theta_{\Lambda'}(1/x)$$
  where $\Lambda' = M^{-T} \mathbb{Z}^k$ is the dual lattice.
- Note $\Lambda$ and $P \Lambda$ have the same theta series for any orthogonal matrix $PP^T=P^TP = I$.

  Let $G = M^T M$. If $G \in \mathbb{Z}^{k \times k}$ then $\Lambda' = M^{-T} \mathbb{Z}^k \supseteq M^{-T} G \mathbb{Z}^k = M \mathbb{Z}^k = \Lambda$. If moreover $\det(G) = 1$ then $G^{-1} \in\mathbb{Z}^{k \times k}$ and $\Lambda= \Lambda'$. The lattice is then said unimodular. We also get $\|\lambda\|^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that

  $$\Theta_\Lambda(2iz)=\Theta_\Lambda(2iz+1), \qquad \Theta_\Lambda(\frac{-2i}{4z}) = (i z)^{-k/2} \Theta_\Lambda(2iz)$$
  and if $8 | k$ then $\Theta_\Lambda(2iz) \in M_{k/2}(\Gamma_0(4))$.
- If also $\|\lambda\|^2 \in 2\mathbb{Z}$ then $\Lambda$ is said even unimodular, in that case $\Theta_\Lambda(iz) \in M_{k/2}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$. This is the case here.
- $M_{8}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ is one-dimensional (containing only the Eisenstein series) so you'll get $\Theta_\Lambda(iz) = E_8(z)$ the Eisenstein series.

Comment: @PaulK I removed that part.. This is what we assume but it is not clear to me what are the properties of $M,A$ making a lattice unimodular/even.

Comment: @PaulK Thanks I edited accordingly